# Google signin sdk in ios giving linker error

Tags: xcode, error-handling, linker, google-signin, gidsignin

I am trying to incorporate Google Sign In into my app.

I have downloaded the Signin SDK and the sample app in it builds and works correctly.

I have tried to get the SDK to work and it is now setup exactly as per the sample app.

However I get the following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Keychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_OpenInChromeController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_GSDK_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
      l011 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
      l059 in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have therefore removed GoogleSignInDependencies.framework from the sample app to see the differences and I get the following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2KeychainCompatibility", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDURLQueryComponent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDServiceConfiguration", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OIDResponseTypeCode", referenced from:
      -[GIDSignIn authenticateInteractivelyWithOptions:] in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthorizationRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate )
  "_OIDOAuthTokenErrorDomain", referenced from:
      ___46-[GIDAuthentication refreshTokensWithHandler:]_block_invoke in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDIDToken", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDGoogleUser_2bdd4a676c033bc6ca21970e75d9159c.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorization", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationEMMChainedDelegate, _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTMAppAuthFetcherAuthorizationWithEMMSupport )
  "_OIDOAuthErrorResponseErrorKey", referenced from:
      +[GIDAuthentication handleTokenFetchEMMError:completion:] in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMKeychain", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthStateMigration_bdf842e92d17b12b5f020e0e721bd017.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OIDAuthState", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDAuthentication_7b83cc27af8929ec7e4c9760d73a0f31.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_f05654be6d1b2af59ab6df426a0c4eb9.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The difference seems to be that my app is using different symbols i.e. those with GSDK in. Can someone tell me what they are please and how I control this difference?

Thanks a lot
Paul

Answer (score 2):

This error was solved by making sure the correct frameworks are in a given folder and that the project is actually using them. The framework search path was picking up some framework that was outdated. With this cleaned up it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding All the frameworks which are listed in **GoogleSignin.framework -> Modules -> Module.modulemap** to **Link Binary with Libraries**